# Update fields from one table to another table

Tags: ms-access-2007

Im trying to update two fields from table into two fields of the same name/datatype in another table. wont work!Here my SQL

```
UPDATE tblEmployeesTemplateTest INNER JOIN tblPersonalWsInDS ON 
tblEmployeesTemplateTest.EMPGivenNameLegal = tblPersonalWsInDS.EMPGivenNameLegal 
SET tblPersonalWsInDS.EMPGivenNameLegal = 
[tblEmployeesTemplateTest].[EMPGivenNameLegal], 
tblPersonalWsInDS.EMPSurnameLegal = 
[tblEmployeesTemplateTest].[EMPSurnameLegal];
```

This will not update any of the fields.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, your query should be formed like below

```
UPDATE TPW  
SET TPW.EMPGivenNameLegal = TET.[EMPGivenNameLegal],
TPW.EMPSurnameLegal = TET.[EMPSurnameLegal]
FROM tblPersonalWsInDS AS TPW
INNER JOIN tblEmployeesTemplateTest AS TET
ON TET.EMPGivenNameLegal = TPW.EMPGivenNameLegal;
```

Comment: @user3606038, don't forget to accept it as answer (by clicking the check button below voting button) if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You always need to update a single table.  So you need to use:

```
UPDATE <table> 
   SET <field> = <value>
       ... 
  FROM <other table/join> 
 WHERE <conditions>;
```

No explicit JOIN here, just the second table in the FROM and the join condition in the WHERE.

AFAICT the JOIN should be syntactically forbidden.  I am surprised the query ran and did nothing instead of erring out.